# How can I update my inner joins results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have two tables:

1. Address (which has 1000+ rows )
2. GoverningBody, (which has just 7)

`dbo.GoverningBody` uses `dbo.Address.AddressID` to link (unique ID)

I want to update all the `address1` columns (from `dbo.Address`) where 
`dbo.address.addressID =dbo.governingbody.addressID`   in my inner join:

```
SELECT 
    GB.GoverningBodyName,
    Ad.Address1,
    Ad.AddressID,
    GB.GoverningBodyID
FROM
    Address Ad
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         GoverningBodyID,
         AddressID,
         GoverningBodyName
     FROM   
         GoverningBody) GB ON ad.AddressID = gb.AddressID
```

I want to update `Address1` values to be something like:

```
'Test1','Test2','Test3' etc...
```

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE testSEQ
AS INT
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1 
CYCLE;
GO

Update Ad
Set Address1 = 'Test' + cast(NEXT VALUE FOR testSEQ as varchar)
From Address Ad
Inner Join GoverningBody GB on ad.AddressID = gb.AddressID
```

Comment: How can I change multiple values at the same time? I don't want them to all be the same, I want them to be different.

Comment: Multiple rows or columns?

Comment: Just the Address1 column.

Comment: Hi Rusland,

Thanks very much for this, however, it doesn't appear to be working. I am getting an error `' Unknown object type 'SEQUENCE' used in a CREATE, DROP, or ALTER statement.'`

Also, how can I update it to be like  "London", "Manchester", etc.

Comment: What version of SQL SERVER do you use?

Comment: You can join table which contains `"London", "Manchester", etc.` and use them

Comment: Hi Ruslan. I am using SSMS 2008 and Visual Studio 2015. The tables don't contain that information in it at the moment so i can't join them as they don't exist.

Comment: CREATE SEQUENCE appeared in SQL Server 2012. 
Anyway you need data source for new Address1 values.

Comment: Could I use a txt document as a data source or a view?

Comment: You can import this data in sql server table. But this is another question ;)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008 has `ROW_NUMBER` function.

I'd wrap your query into a CTE (common-table expression) with an extra column for row numbers and update the CTE. You can use `ORDER BY` in the `ROW_NUMBER` function to determine how the numbers will be assigned to rows.

By the way, your `INNER JOIN` doesn't really need sub-query, it can be written in a much simpler form. The optimiser is smart enough to read only those columns that are needed. In fact, in the `UPDATE` query you don't need `GoverningBodyName` and `GoverningBodyID` columns and most likely optimiser would not read them.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
        GB.GoverningBodyName,
        Ad.Address1,
        Ad.AddressID,
        GB.GoverningBodyID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Ad.AddressID) AS rn
    FROM
        Address AS Ad
        INNER JOIN GoverningBody AS GB ON ad.AddressID = gb.AddressID
)
UPDATE CTE
SET Address1 = 'Test' + CAST(rn as varchar(10))
;
```